# Stream reduction identity vs. idempotent value

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, reduction, idempotent

The [`java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) package documentation gives this definition for *identity* in the context of reduction:

> the `identity` value must be an *identity* for the combiner function. This means that for all `u`, `combiner.apply(identity, u)` is equal to `u`.

[`Stream.reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) and its primitive counterparts offer a similar definition.

As far as I understand, this definition is necessary to support parallel streams. For example, a non-zero seed value for a sum reduction could be multiplied by the number of parallel processors, distorting the final result unpredictably.

But this definition seems stricter than necessary to support parallelism. Why not require an [*idempotent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Idempotent_elements_and_binary_operations) value `x`, such that `combiner.apply(x, x)` is equal to `x`? This would protect functions like `Integer::sum`, `(a, b) -> a * b` and `String::concat` from skewing across multiple processes, while still allowing the use of any seed with idempotent functions like `Math::max`, `(a, b) -> a | b` and [`Sets::intersection`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-).

Is there some unique benefit to an identity value that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not enough to ask "why not?" and offer some examples where it won't cause a problem.  You have to offer a proof that with this relaxed requirement, sequential and parallel evaluations are guaranteed to produce the same correct result.

Let's use the 2-argument reduce to simplify matters.  Let's also limit ourselves to a stream with 2 elements (*a*, *b*). let identity be *i* and accumulator be *op*.

When evaluated sequentially, the result is *(i op a) op b*.  When evaluated in parallel, it might be *(i op a) op (i op b)* (or there might even be a naked *i* in between, but let's not worry about that for now).  And we want both of those to equal *a op b*

If *i* is required to be an identity, it is easy to see that both sequential and parallel evaluations will be correct.  But if all we require of *i* is that *i op i = i*, then it does not obviously follow that *(i op a) op (i op b)* must equals *a op b* for any associative *op* and any *a* and *b*.

One counter-example I can think of is space-collapsing concatenation:  `(x, y) -> (x + y).replaceAll(" +", " ")`.  It is associative and `" "` is idempotent but not an identity with respect to this function.  Parallel and sequential evaluations will yield different results.

Comment: Nice answer, but I can't help but wonder if there exists some rule that would work for the examples I gave.

Comment: @shmosel All the examples you gave are for accumulator function that is commutative (in addition to associative).  If the operation is commutative and the "initial value" is idempotent, then parallel reduction will be equivalent to sequential (I *think*).

Answer (score 0):

Why would `combiner.apply(x, x) == x` be a good definition of *identity*?

Say the combiner is `max()`. Sure, `max(x, x) == x` is true. It is actually true for any `x`, which means that *any* value would be a good `identity` value for `max()`.

That is certainly not true, since the only valid *identity* value for `max()` combiner is `MIN_VALUE` (or a "no value" such as `null` or `NaN`, assuming combiner understands and ignores such a value).

Comment: I'm not suggesting an alternative definition of *identity*. I'm saying we don't need such a strict rule to support parallel reduction. In other words, *why not* allow any value as a seed for `max()`?

Comment: Because a seed value of e.g. `5` is not good if the stream only contains values less than 5. It has nothing to do with parallel processing. It's a requirement that including the `identity` value in the set of values given to the combiner, will not affect the result. E.g. only one identity value is neutral to primitive addition: `0`. Only one for primitive multiplication: `1`.

Comment: Why is it "not good"? Of course it'll affect the result, but that's to be expected.